# Translate URL without spaces

Tags: google-translate, translate

I am seeing some traffic from domains that are not written in a language I can read.  I tried to translate them with Google translate, however, I get mixed results depending on where I place spaces.

For example:
sahoaofofiisahoatwneansoha

Depending on where I place spaces I get African or Japanese translations.  Of course, this could just be random letters but has anyone come across a method or service for translating URLs and overcoming the space location challenge.

Any guidance is welcome :)  Thanks!

Comment: Is this related to programming in any way?

Comment: A python script utilising the google translate API could be a programming proposal.  I am not sure how I would efficiently break up the string into logical smaller strings